# Cloudformation: Not able to update AMI

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am not able to update AMI on my launch configuration. Here is the error I see

[image]

and it rolls back. I checked the reason on google and it should work fine even if there are running instances, just that it won't update the already running instances. But, it does not work like that in our case. Please suggest!

Comment: Are you sure you (or that the role passed to the CloudFormation stack) have the proper IAM permission?

Comment: yes. I have dev stack and QA stack in my AWS account. For dev stack, updating AMI works fine but on QA it fails. Both dev and QA use same IAM role.

Comment: I'm still confident that it has something to do with IAM permissions, but for the sake of having all the details: are the 2 stacks in the same region? AMIs have different IDs depending on the region.